# Windows 10, Python2.7 sys.argv grep question marks

Tags: windows, python-2.7, encoding

---

i have a poblem when python take arguments from windows console printed in cyrillic.

```
import sys
print type(sys.argv[1])
print sys.argv[1].decode('cp437')
```

I try:
`C:\>python2 C:\MyFolder\Projects\hh_transform\trouble.py "Иванов Иван Иванович"`

But i always got the question marks:
`?????? ???? ????????`

I tried (in my system default encoding is cp437) to execute:

`chcp 65001 & set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

And changed my code like this (in any possable combinations):
`sys.argv[1].decode("cp437").encode("utf-8")`

But input always looks the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLln.png). What shoud i do?

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6 :)

Comment: You could also switch your system locale to Russian.